# Estimating (c-1) from approximation of c

Tags: approximation-algorithms

If we have a FPRAS for approximating the quantity c, can we get another FPRAS for estimating (c-1) using the estimation of c?

Comment: What does FPRAS mean?

Comment: @vonbrand [Fully-polynomial randomized approximation scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme#Randomized).

Answer (score 2):

No. An FPRAS for a function $f$ must return an answer between $(1-\epsilon)f(x)$ and $(1+\epsilon)f(x)$ say 75% of the time. Therefore, if $f(x)=0$, an FPRAS for $f$ must return *exactly* zero, at least 75% of the time: an FPRAS must be able to reliably distinguish zero from non-zero. It does not, however, have to reliably distinguish $y$ from not-$y$ for any $y\neq 0$.

In more detail, suppose we have an FPRAS for a function $f(x)$ and we want to produce an FPRAS for $f(x)-1$.  If $f(x)=1$ for some $x$, the FPRAS will give an answer in the range $1\pm\epsilon$, 75% of the time. Just subtracting $1$ from the result of the FPRAS gives an answer within the range $\pm\epsilon$, 75% of the time but an FPRAS for $f(x)-1$ would have to give exactly zero, 75% of the time.